# Using the Marketing Cloud connector, does Mobile Push tracking data sync to Salesforce contacts in the same way email tracking data does?

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, mobilepush

If we want our customer service agents (who use Salesforce Service Cloud) to see Push message interaction history for Salesforce contacts, what are our options?

Email interaction data is sychronised via our use of the Marketing Cloud connector and we will be using the Salesforce Contact ID in our Mobile Push implementation, so I'm hoping there's a way to have all the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push interaction data passed back.

Answer (score 0):

After more research and speaking to others on this, it appears that email tracking data is all that is sent to Salesforce via the connector. One solution is to do the work manually, creating a custom object (which the connector does for you in the case of email sends) and populating this with the Push engagement information.